# How to convert timezone of a lookup activity in Azure Data Factory

Tags: datetime, azure-data-factory

My source dataset in Azure Data Factory is returning me values in UTC timezone. I am trying to convert these values into AUS Eastern Standard Time but the function convertTimeZone() is not working for me. It doesn't matter which timezone I use, I always get the same error. I am attempting to do this in the query section of my source dataset within a copy activity.

My code is the below

```
@concat(
'SELECT sys_id_value, number_value, sys_updated_on_value  FROM tablename WHERE sys_updated_on_value > '''
,convertTimeZone(activity('LookupOldWaterMarkActivity').output.firstRow.watermarkvalue,'UTC','AUS Eastern Standard Time', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
,''''
, ' AND sys_updated_on_value <= '''
,convertTimeZone(activity('LookupNewWaterMarkActivity').output.firstRow.watermarkvalue,'UTC','AUS Eastern Standard Time', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
,''''
)
```

I get the below error message

The parameters and expression cannot be resolved for schema operations. Error Message: {
"message": "ErrorCode=InvalidTemplate, ErrorMessage=In the function 'convertTimeZone', the value provided for the time zone id 'AUS Eastern Standard Time' was not valid. "

Additionally, I will also need to change the sys_updated_on_value column that gets inserted into my sink source to also be in AUS Eastern Standard Time. How would I do this? Do I convertTimeZone in the select clause of my above query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for convertTimeZone is as per below:

```
convertTimeZone('<timestamp>', '<sourceTimeZone>', '<destinationTimeZone>', '<format>'?)
```

The **format** parameter take the value in below format:

`yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss:fffffffK` or `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss`.

Please take reference from official document [convertTimeZone()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#converttimezone) and similar kind of thread on [Microsoft Power Automate Community forum](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/convertTimeZone-results-in-invalid-time-zone-id-error/td-p/617484) for better understanding.

Comment: Is that not what I have done already? 

My <timestamp> is : activity('LookupOldWaterMarkActivity').output.firstRow.watermarkvalue
My <sourceTimeZone> is: UTC
My <destinationTimeZone> is: AUS Eastern Standard Time
My <format> is yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss 

Even if I change my format to be one you suggested, still doesn't work

Comment: instead of using this expression in `concat`, just simply use it separately to make sure your data is incorrect format.

Comment: How will I do this outside of the concat? I need to have it in my WHERE clause as I need to filter results to be between those 2 dates. Is there a way of doing this outside of the concat?

Comment: take the sample data from `activity('LookupOldWaterMarkActivity').output.firstRow.watermarkvalue` manually and put it in expression in data flow or any other activity and use the same format which you are using.